# Find a brief argue that the scheme $B\phi\rightarrow \hat{B}B\phi$ is valid.

Tags: logic

I would like to find a briefly argue that the scheme $B\phi\rightarrow \hat{B}B\phi$ is a valid principle of the basic doxastic logic.

This is from an exercise I have in Doxastic logic, but in the solution they only present that the schedule is valid and not an argument about why it is valid, and to understand this more I would appreciate help with an argument about why it is valid.

I started by trying to decipher the schedule and got it to: *The agent knows that $\phi$ implies that the agent consider it possible that she knows $\phi$.*

In a counter-argument I had consider a model of two indistinguishable for the agent worlds, in one of which p is true and in the other false. But can I really do this in a proof that the scheme is valid?

Thanks in advance!

**Edit**: Language of DXL: same as that for EL, but with the belief operator B instead of K. The other propositional connectives are definable as usual. Denote $\hat{B}\varphi = \neg B \neg \varphi$.

Some basic principles of DXL:

**K** $\ \ \ \ B\varphi \wedge B(\varphi \rightarrow \psi)\rightarrow B\psi$

**D** $\ \ \ \ B\varphi \rightarrow \hat{B}\varphi$

**4** $\ \ \ \ B\varphi \rightarrow BB\varphi$

**5** $\ \ \ \ \neg B\varphi \rightarrow B \neg B \varphi$

Comment: Possibilist logic ? Say it....

Comment: @JeanMarie This is from the course philosophical logic and deals with Doxastic logic.

Comment: How are $B$ and $\hat{B}$ defined? Without the hat, the formula above holds because of the transitivity of the underlying Kripke frame.

Comment: This is impossible to answer unless you tell us what you mean by "the basic doxastic logic" - either by way of a proof system or a semantics.

Comment: @AlexKruckman I edited the text now with what I have about the semantics.

Comment: That's the proof system, not the semantics, but ok! It finally clarifies what you're asking.  (The semantics are probably transitive, serial, and Euclidean Kripke frames)

Comment: I think there's a typo in your statement of K. Should be $(B\varphi \wedge B(\varphi \rightarrow \psi))\rightarrow B\psi$ or equivalently $B(\varphi \rightarrow \psi)\rightarrow (B\varphi \rightarrow B\psi)$.

Comment: @AlexKruckman Thank you! And you are correct, there's a typo in my statement, I will edit this now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $B\varphi$. By 4, $BB\varphi$. By D, $\hat{B}B\varphi$. So $B\varphi\rightarrow \hat{B}B\varphi$.

---

**Edit:** Based on your follow-up question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4129899/7062), it's possible that this was supposed to be more of a philosophical question than a mathematical one. That is, it's possible that you're being asked not for a formal proof of this sentence from K, D, 4, and 5, but rather an intuitive justification that the sentence is valid "in the world" based on the doxastic interpretation of the modal operator $B$ as "belief".

In this case, the proof above could be transformed into an explanation for the intuitive validity of this principle based on the intuitive validity of the principles 4 and D.