# State and argue briefly whether $\hat{K}B\phi\rightarrow \hat{K}\phi$ should be a valid principle

Tags: logic

State and argue briefly whether the scheme $\hat{K}B\phi\rightarrow \hat{K}\phi$ should be a valid principle of the Epistemic Doxastic Logic (EDL).

**Some principles expressed in EDL:**

**1. (a)** $\ \ K\varphi\rightarrow B\varphi; \ \ \ \ \ \ \ $ **(b)** $\ \ B\varphi\rightarrow K\varphi$

**2. (a)** $\ \ \hat{K}\varphi\rightarrow B\varphi; \ \ \ \ \ \ \ $ **(b)** $\ \ B\varphi\rightarrow \hat{K}\varphi$

**3. (a)** $\ \ B\varphi\rightarrow KB\varphi; \ \ \ \ $ **(b)** $\ \ B\varphi\rightarrow BK\varphi$

**4. (a)** $\ \ K\varphi\rightarrow KB\varphi; \ \ \ \ $ **(b)** $\ \ K\varphi\rightarrow BK\varphi$

**5. (a)** $\ \ KB\varphi\rightarrow BK\varphi; \ \ $ **(b)** $\ \ BK\varphi\rightarrow KB\varphi$

I came to the conclusion that this is not a valid principle by first assuming $B\varphi$, then by 2b we get that $B\varphi \rightarrow \hat{K}\varphi$. But for no principle it applies that K and B together implies K itself and therefore it must be false.

Is this a complete proof or am I missing something? It feels a bit thin.

**Edit:** For context see my previous [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4129257/find-a-brief-argue-that-the-scheme-b-phi-rightarrow-hatbb-phi-is-valid)

Comment: You should refer to your previous post https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4129257 for context.

Comment: @JeanMarie Thank you for your info! I edited this just know.

Answer (score 1):

No, what you've written is not a complete proof. You can't show that something is *not* provable by starting to give a proof and then claiming it can't be finished. Maybe there's some other totally different proof that doesn't start by assuming $B\varphi$ and applying 2(b). If you want to show that a sentence is not provable, the best method is to provide a countermodel.

Taking a step back, though, there's something odd about this question: The 10 axioms your wrote down are almost certainly not intended to be taken together as the axioms of some logic. Taking 1.(a) and (b), 2.(a) and (b), and 3.(a) and (b)  together, they imply that $K\varphi$, $B\varphi$, $\hat{K}\varphi$ are all equivalent, which serves to trivialize the situation: Now up to equivalence there is only one modal operator $K$, which is equivalent to its dual $\hat{K} = \lnot K \lnot$.

Instead, I would interpret these 10 axioms as optional principles that you might or might not want to include in your logic. They each express some relationship between $K$ and $B$, and intepreting $K$ and "knowledge" and $B$ as "belief", they might be accepted or rejected on philosophical grounds, based on your views about the meanings of "knowledge" and "belief".

Together with the phrasing:

> State and argue briefly whether the scheme $\hat{K}B\varphi\rightarrow \hat{K}\varphi$ **should** be a valid principle of the Epistemic Doxastic Logic (EDL)

this makes me think that you might be misinterpreting the question. Instead of giving a proof that $\hat{K}B\varphi\rightarrow \hat{K}\varphi$ is provable or not in some fixed system, it seems like you're being asked to give an intuitive argument about the relationship between "knowledge" and "belief" that would support or refute the validity of $\hat{K}B\varphi\rightarrow \hat{K}\varphi$ as a "truth about the world". You might translate this sentence as "If it's not the case that I know I don't believe $\varphi$, then it's not the case that I know $\varphi$ is false", or maybe "If as far as I know, I might believe $\varphi$, then as far as I know, $\varphi$ might be true". If I'm interpreting the question correctly, it's a question of philosophy rather than mathematics, and there's not necessarily one right answer.